# Eigenvalues of matrix of order n

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

I am trying to find eigen values of following matrix.Following matrix is positive semi definite matrix(i.e. All of its eigen values are non negative). I had applied several rows operations to find eigen values but I don't know how go for further calculation.

$A= \begin{bmatrix}
2 & -1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & ... & 0 \\
-1 & 3 & -1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & ... & 0 \\
-1 & -1 & 4 & -1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & ... & 0 \\
0 & -1 & -1 & 4 & -1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & ... & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & -1 & 4 & -1 & -1 & 0 & ... & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & -1 & 4 & -1 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & -1 & 3 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & -1 & 2 \\
  \end{bmatrix}_{n \times n}$

Characteristic Polynomial is $|\lambda I - A| =0 $

$\therefore \begin{vmatrix}
\lambda - 2 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & ... & 0 \\
1 & \lambda - 3 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & ... & 0 \\
1 & 1 & \lambda - 4 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & ... & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & \lambda - 4 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & ... & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & \lambda - 4 & 1 & 1 & 0 & ... & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & \lambda - 4 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & \lambda - 3 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & \lambda - 2 \\
\end{vmatrix} = 0 $

Taking $R_1+R_i$ for each $i=2,3,4...n-1$

$\therefore \begin{vmatrix}
\lambda  & \lambda & \lambda & \lambda & \lambda & \lambda & \lambda & \lambda & ... & \lambda \\
1 & \lambda - 3 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & ... & 0 \\
1 & 1 & \lambda - 4  & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & ... & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & \lambda - 4 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & ... & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & \lambda - 4 & 1 & 1 & 0 & ... & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & \lambda - 4 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & \lambda - 3 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & \lambda - 2 \\
\end{vmatrix} = 0 $

Taking $R_1(\frac{1}{\lambda})$

$\therefore  \lambda \begin{vmatrix}
1  & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ... & 1 \\
1 & \lambda - 3 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & ... & 0 \\
1 & 1 & \lambda - 4  & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & ... & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & \lambda - 4 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & ... & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & \lambda - 4 & 1 & 1 & 0 & ... & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & \lambda - 4 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & \lambda - 3 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & \lambda - 2 \\
\end{vmatrix} = 0 $

Taking $R_2-R_1$ and $R_3-R_1$

$\therefore  \lambda \begin{vmatrix}
1  & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ... & 1 \\
0 & \lambda - 4 & 0 & 0 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & ... & -1 \\
0 & 0 & \lambda - 5  & 0 & 0 & -1 & -1 & -1 & ... & -1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & \lambda - 4 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & ... & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & \lambda - 4 & 1 & 1 & 0 & ... & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & \lambda - 4 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & \lambda - 3 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & \lambda - 2 \\
\end{vmatrix} = 0 $

$\therefore  \lambda \begin{vmatrix}
\lambda - 4 & 0 & 0 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & ... & -1 \\
0 & \lambda - 5  & 0 & 0 & -1 & -1 & -1 & ... & -1 \\
1 & 1 & \lambda - 4 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & ... & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & \lambda - 4 & 1 & 1 & 0 & ... & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & \lambda - 4 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & \lambda - 3 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & \lambda - 2 \\
\end{vmatrix}_{n-1 \times n-1} = 0 $

Now what to do for further calculation?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Someone might prove me wrong, but: do you have any reason to expect the eigenvalues to be of some nice form? Even if you were able to finish your determinant, you would be left with a polynomial of degree  $n $: how would you find its roots?

Comment: You might try calculating the simplest example, $n=5$, to get some idea of what the answer is going to look like.

Comment: I had tried it but it doesn't work for me

Comment: For n=4,the answer is 0,2,4,4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I define eigenvalues by being roots of $det(A-\lambda I)=0$.
The first size which has the given structure, i.e., $5 \times 5$ (as advised by @Gerry Myerson)

$A=\begin{pmatrix}2 & -1 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\ - 1 & 3 & -1 & -1 & 0 \\ - 1 & -1 & 4 & -1 & -1 \\ 0 & -1 & -1 & 3 & -1 \\0 & 0 & -1 & -1 & 2\end{pmatrix}$

I have submitted the issue to Mathematica. The eigenvalues of $A$ are $0, 3 \pm \sqrt{2}, 3, 5$. Beyond $5 \times 5$, no simple set of eigenvalues can be found.

(the eigenvalue $0$ is present for each dimension, as your computation proves it)

Here are the characteristic polynomials for the size $5 \times 5$ to $10 \times 10$. One can notice certain "regularities" on certain coefficients.

$\chi_5(x)=-105 x + 146 x^2 - 70 x^3 + 14 x^4 -
   x^5$

$\chi_6(x)=-330 x + 611 x^2 - 404 x^3 + 124 x^4 - 18 
x^5 + x^6$

$\chi_7(x)=-1008 x + 2396 x^2 - 2064 x^3 + 870 x^4 - 194 x^5 + 22 
    x^6 - x^7$

$\chi_8(x)=-3016 x + 8954 x^2 - 9670 x^3 + 5265 x^4 - 1608 x^5 + 280 
    x^6 - 26 x^7 + x^8$

$\chi_9(x)=-8883 x + 32216 x^2 - 
    42443 x^3 + 28696 x^4 - 11270 x^5 + 2682 x^6 - 382 
  x^7 + 30 x^8 - x^9$

$\chi_{10}(x)=-25840 x + 112428 x^2 - 
      176972 x^3 + 144524 x^4 - 70114 x^5 + 21391 x^6 - 4156 x^7 + 
    500 x^8 - 34 x^9 + x^{10}$